# Unsupported Data Type when using SQL Data Sync to Azure

Tags: sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database, clustered-index, azure-data-sync

I'd like to sync an on-premise SQL Server 2012 SP2 database to Azure using SQL Data Sync.
When I try to do the sync I get "Unsupported Data Type" error on one of the tables for the ID_Index column:

[image]

The Azure Management Portal gives no further explanantion for the error.
The table design in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

The table creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FlightPlanData](
  [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_FlightPlanData_ID]  DEFAULT (newid()),
  [Airline_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [FlightID_FK] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [FlightPlanID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [DateInserted] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_FlightPlanData_DateInserted]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
  [Type] [varchar](20) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_FlightPlanData_Type]  DEFAULT (''),
  [FileName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_FlightPlanData_FileName]  DEFAULT (''),
  [ClientID_FK] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
  [ID_Index] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_FlightPlanData] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID] ASC))

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FlightPlanData] ON [dbo].[FlightPlanData]([ID_Index] ASC)
```

The table has a GUID primary key, but it's not clustered, instead we use a clustered in index (ID_Index).
I can't remove the ID_Index column, and I'd prefer not to make it the primary key. Is there any way to solve this? 
I heard Azure requires a clustered index for each table, but it doesn't have to be the primary key. So what's the problem here?

Comment: Just a guess, but it's possible that SQL Data Sync doesn't support non-primary-key identity columns. What if you were to make ID_Index a uniqueidentifier instead of an int?

Answer (score 0):

A table cannot have an identity column that is not the primary key. This is one of the general requirements of SQL Data Sync. For more information, please visit [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data.md) GitHub documentation.